# Avatar de usuários novos

Tags: suporte, novos-usuários

Tenho observado que usuários novos aparecem com diversos tipos de avatar padrão:

- Gravatar com figuras geométricas coloridas simétricas. Exemplos: [image] [image]
- Bonequinho azul (vindo do google). [image]
- Silhueta sobre fundo cinza (vindo do facebook). [image]
- Letra sobre fundo colorido (vindo do google). Exemplos: [image] [image]

Gostaria de saber por qual critério que um desses avatares é escolhido para o usuário recém-cadastrado.

Comment: Isso não teria a ver com o login social? Se o cara logou pelo facebook ou pela conta google etc?

Comment: Não sei se devo colocar como comentário ou resposta, mas lá vamos: Quando um usuário se cadasta aqui, automaticamente é pego uma foto/avatar do site de onde ele veio, ou seja, da rede social que ele usou para se cadastrar. Caso a pessoa tenha um perfil ativo numa rede social com foto e tudo mais, ela também aparecerá aqui. Pelo que eu saiba, não tem como distinguir se a pessoa está sem foto numa rede social, ou se está usando a padrão, sendo assim, todos ganham aquele avatar/imagem do site/rede social anterior.